# HTTP 403 Error message when accessing Alexa Device Address API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When trying to call the Alexa Device Address API using the following HTTPS endpoint;

**apiEndpoint**/v1/devices/**deviceId**/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode

Header:
Authorization, "Bearer eyJ..... **apiAccessToken**"

I receive back an HTTP 403 response with an error message saying

> {
>   "type": "FORBIDDEN", 
>   "message": "The authentication token is not valid." 
>   }

I have enabled the countryAndPostalCode permission in the skill, and ensured that it is granted within the Alexa iOS app.

The skill itself is still under development (not published), it's in the en-GB locale, and I'm testing from the Alexa iOS app under the same Amazon account.

Comment: I've based my code on this post https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/get-location-or-address-from-alexa-skill-7f85ec92dd59 - It's in Node.js

Comment: Look through this article and check that you are hitting the correct api endpoint for a device in the EU   http://www.enticom.co.uk/php/retrieve-the-location-from-an-amazon-alexa-device/

Comment: @ChuckLaPress - This example uses a ConsentToken, which is deprecated according to Amazon ( https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html#get-the-api-access-token-and-device-id )

Comment: Oh, I see you are following this structure https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-device-address-api/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js   so are you returning an auth token from your launch intent?

Comment: Try the latest sdk version and Alexa Service API instead of raw request (sample [here](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-device-address-api/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js), more docs [here](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Calling-Alexa-Service-APIs.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have enabled the countryAndPostalCode permission in the skill, and
>   ensured that it is granted within the Alexa iOS app.

To be safe, I suggest you to triple-check by navigating to Skill Settings > Permissions > Manage Permissions, and make sure the toggle for "Device Country and Postal Code" is enabled. I have seen some inconsistency on Android between the status shown on the Skill Settings page and the actual toggle state.

Double-check your header: `{"Authorization": "Bearer " + apiAccessToken}`. As you mentioned, `consentToken` has been deprecated, so it should be `apiAccessToken`. Also make sure you have a space between `Bearer` and `apiAccessToken`.

If it still doesn't work, try re-enabling the Skill. Perhaps you got into a bad state somehow.

As a side note, apparently it does not allow you to call the countryAndPostalCode API even if you have permission to retrieve the full address. So if you requested the full address permission, you have to call the full address API.

Comment: Thanks!, it was the space between Bearer and apiAccessToken

Comment: The side note was it for me. Changed from `/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode` to `/settings/address` and my requests stopped getting rejected.